# Run bash commands inside container with alias

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

We have docker contianers, and i would like to run a bash command inside my container, through a script. Like so:

```bash
bin/run-in-container ls -la
```

where the script run-in-container looks something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker compose exec container_name bash -ic "$@"
```

I cannot get my script to interpret all parameters, inside single quotes.

| this interprets to | `docker compose exec api bash -ic ls -la` |
| --- | --- |
| but what I want to to interpret is | `docker compose exec api bash -ic 'ls -la'` |

If i try to concatenate a string of single quotes and my parameters, it renders the character escaped:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

escaped_single_qoute="'"
docker compose exec container_name bash -ic $escaped_single_qoute "$@" $escaped_single_qoute
```

But this interprets into :

```bash
docker compose exec api bash -ic ''\''ls' '-la'\'''
```

Here is a MCVE: [gist with Dockerfile and code](https://gist.github.com/AndersSpringborg/56ca18396dd48fd1db10b5e781912681)

```yaml
services:
  node:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: 888aaen/bash_stackoverflow:latest 

    volumes:
      # Mount .bash_aliases file.
      - "./.bash_aliases:/home/node/.bash_aliases"
```

script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker compose exec node bash -ic "$@"
```

## UPDATE: not solved

[KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) came with a great solution, but this does not run with aliases inside the contianer.

```bash
docker compose exec container_name bash -ic '"$@"' _ "$@"
# usage example: ./script ls -la
# usage example: ./script sh -c "ls -la ; echo another command"
```

Let's say we have these aliases:

```
# ~/.bash_aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -la'
```

I want to be able to run

```
bin/run-in-container ll
```

| which is possible with | `docker compose exec api bash -ic 'la src/'` |
| --- | --- |
| but not with | `bin/run-in-container la src/` |

Comment: Why not just `docker compose exec container_name "$@"`? `But this interprets into :` Yes, _you_ type quotes they are different when you concatenate them, there are different parsing rules.

Comment: This do not behave correctly inside the container. This only runs `ls` and not `ls -la` or something like `ls src/test`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your comment. With `version: "3" services: alpine: image: alpine command: sleep 1h`, followed by `docker compose up` and `docker compose exec alpnie ls -la` correctly lists `/` directory. Post an MCVE or it didn't happen.

Comment: I've updated the description, with a MCVE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a single command, just pass the command:

```
docker compose exec container_name "$@"
# usage example: ./script ls -la
# usage example: ./script sh -c "ls -la ; echo another command"
```

If you want to pass a single command with an (odd?) requirement in running the command inside bash interactive shell, you would forward the arguments and execute them inside the shell:

```
docker compose exec container_name bash -ic '"$@"' _ "$@"
# usage example: ./script ls -la
# usage example: ./script sh -c "ls -la ; echo another command"
```

If you want to pass a shell script, just like to eval, just concatenate arguments with space:

```
docker compose exec container_name bash -ic "$*"
# usage example: ./script ls -la
# usage example: ./script ls -la ';' echo another command
# usage example: ./script "$(printf "%q " sh -c "ls -la ; echo another command")"
```

> Let's say we have these aliases:

That's all unorthodox. Aliases are for interactive shells, the 1000 years old advice is to use functions instead of aliases. `.bash_aliases` is a nonstandard (but common) file, that is *not* being sourced on bash startup *unless* explicitly mentioned in `.bashrc` file for interactive non-login shell. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html .

If your intention is to provide `ll` command for non-interactive use, instead create an executable in `/usr/local/bin` named `ll` that will call `ls -l "$@"` in it.

Another common convention, is to put **functions** (not aliases! aliases are for interactive shells) inside `/etc/profile.d` and then run an **login** **non**-interactive shell. People are used to doing `sh -l` when needing environment over ssh, the convention is somewhat understood by users.

Comment: Thanks man. the second example is what I was looking for.❤️ I didn't know of the syntax you put in the second example. How does that work? Dose `_` replace arguments inside single quotes?

Comment: I realise now, that this do not fix my problem. Commands are ran without aliases pressent. So if have an alias `la='ls -la'` i cannot run `./script la` in my own shell

Comment: Here i mean aliases inside the container. In our case we have a `test` alias inside each container. In one container `test='npx jest` and in another `test=dotnet test`

Comment: `mean aliases` aliases are for interactive use. If you do not want to do something interactive, do not use aliases. Use functions, or the best is to use executable files in PATH. `test alias` That's a bad idea, there is already a very super standard POSIX test command. If that alias would overwrite the standard test command, it would break most of the shell scripts. Consider using a different name.

Comment: It is not named test, that was for a simple explanation. Our workflow atm is to go into an interactive shell inside the container, then run the command.

`me@local $ bin/api`
`app@remote_container $ ci`